# Multiplication of doubles results in 1.03614557927664E-317

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this statement

```
  CurrentStateList[StateIndex].Probability = TempNumber * SingleProbability.Number;
```

TempNumber equals 8, SingleProbability.Number equals 1.5.

Those variables and CurrentStateList.Probability are all double, yet somehow after this statement CurrentStateList[StateIndex].Probability equals 1.03614557927664E-317.

The same happens when SingleProbability.Number equals 2. There must be something obvious that I am missing.  The debugger doesn't throw any warnings about types or errors it's just that the result doesn't make sense.

I posted screenshot as you can see CurrentStateList[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYPRb.png).Probability is now this strange number. While TempNumber is 8 and SingleProbability is 1.5.
[ScreenShot][1]

[Probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYPRb.png)

Comment: What result were you expecting? That number is basically 0.

Comment: There is something i do not understand then. 8 * 1.5 should be 12 no?

Comment: Should. Are you ***sure*** the variables have those values?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? A screenshot showing all the variables? The implementation of `Whatever.Probability`? If this is true then there is a horrible bug in unity. I'm leaning towards your assumptions being wrong first.

Comment: I posted a screenshot and i am indeed hoping some of my assumptions are wrong, but can't figure out which exactly.

Comment: And now the declaration/implementation of that `Probability` property.

Comment: What's the type of `CurrentStateList[StateIndex]`? Is it a class or a struct?

Comment: Also, what is `StateClass`, is it indeed a class, or is it a struct?

Comment: I updated once again, had to delete first screenshot since it only allowed me to post one link. Even though it said i can post 2.

Comment: Here is the first screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNCx8.png

Comment: Thank you for doing screenshots, but please be careful not to hide the `Type` column, it might be important. We can *guess* here that both numbers are indeed of type `System.Double`, but not completely certain.

Comment: Are you sure that you are inspecting the values with your debugger stopped **just after the line copied in your question** ? It is not shown in the screenshot.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV79G.png In this screenshot you should see types and line where debugger was stoped.

Comment: One "obvious" possible thing is that the same variable is accessed by another thread. Is that possible ? Are the elements of `CurrentStateList` shared among other classes ?

Comment: **No useful information in the question to help you...** As someone already said 8 * 1.5 is equal to 12. So some important information is missing.